# C++ Is it right to use constexpr in size declaration

Tags: c++, size

I'm trying to make sizes declaration is it right to use `constexpr`

```
#define BYTE ((size_t)1)
#define KIB   (constexpr BYTE * (size_t)1024)
#define MIB   (constexpr KIB   * (size_t)1024)
#define GIB   (constexpr MIB   * (size_t)1024)
```

Comment: This is not how you use `constexpr`. It's not needed here at all. But it would be better to replace macros with constexpr variables.

Comment: `BYTE` is probably not the best choice of macro name. Iirc `windows.h` introduces a type alias `BYTE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `constexpr` keyword can't be used as part of an expression. It just makes no syntactical sense in the position you are using it. `constexpr` is a qualifier on a declaration for a variable or function.

There is no point in using a macro like this. You can declare these constants as `constexpr` variables:

```
constexpr size_t BYTE = 1;
constexpr size_t KIB = BYTE * 1024;
constexpr size_t MIB = KIB * 1024;
constexpr size_t GIB = MIB * 1024;
```

You don't even need the `constexpr`. It will work with just `const` instead exactly the same. However `constexpr` makes the intention of these being compile-time constants clearer and will avoid making mistakes causing them *not* to be compile-time constants.

Also, the explicit casts to `size_t` are not needed. Usual arithmetic conversions will make sure that the second operand is converted to `size_t` as well. (I suppose technically it is allowed for `size_t` to have lower rank than `int`, in which case it may be a problem, which however can be avoided by using unsigned literals `1024U` instead of signed `int`. But if we are talking about weird platforms like that `size_t` might also be too small to hold the values you want to compute here.)

---

Since C++17 it is slightly safer to additionally qualify the variables with `inline`. This has the effect of giving the variables *external* linkage while still making it possible to define them in multiple translation units. Otherwise they have *internal* linkage, which usually is not a problem, however one might take the address of the variable and use it e.g. in the definition of an `inline` function. Then having internal linkage for the variable would cause an ODR violation on the `inline` function definition.